# Open website in Python standalone application without using browser

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make an application which looks something like this image:

[image]

I need it to open a website on click of the button.

I used a Tkinter code which looks like this:

```
def openweb():
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
Btn = Button(root, text = "Check URL",command=openweb)
```

But it is opening in the default browser.

Is there some way to handle it?

Comment: Definitely there's a way.

Comment: so you want the web page to open on your application or you want the web page to open a browser of  your choosing?

Comment: @Hamuel I want the web page to open in my application.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Can you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the little code you posted I guess you're using Tkinter – it doesn't come with an embeddable browser frame component, unfortunately.

You'll have to switch to something more complex like Qt (PyQt5 / PySide2) if you need an app that embeds a web browser view.

Comment: Yes I am using Tkinter. And thanks a lot. Will try doing it using QT